# preg_match regex to include dashes in words?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
 $name = 'Canon OEM BC-30e BK';
 preg_match("/OEM (\\w+)/", $name, $matches);
 $hash = $matches[1];
```

How can I get $hash to return 'BC-30e' in this example? Right now it is returning 'BC-'. I'm a bit new to learning regular expressions and am struggling to get the result intended. I've been over on http://regexr.com/ trying to hammer it out for a minute and am finding this result difficult. =(

To my understanding the 'w' is making it a word, which is excluding dashes. However when I change it to something like below I simply get 'B.'

```
 $name = 'Canon OEM BC-30e BK';
 preg_match("/OEM ([A-Za-z-])/", $name, $matches);
 $hash = $matches[1];
```

Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here? I would be most appreciative =)

Comment: test not space `OEM ([\\S]+)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That's what I was looking for! Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find non-space characters:

```
/OEM ([\\S]+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to match multiple characters and add digits in your last regex:

```
preg_match("/OEM ([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/", $name, $matches);
```

Comment: i does not return what OP wants

Comment: @splash58 is correct this returned the same 'BC-' result

Comment: The numeric digits are missing from the character class ... edited.